# Return multiple HOC components from Array in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

I am trying to declare and return multiple HOC's from any array, but keep being returned a "Functions are not valid as a React child." Error. Has anyone ran into this issue before?

JS:

```
....

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center"
};

const withRequestAnimationFrame = () => WrappedComponent => {
  class RequestAnimationFrame extends Component {
    state = {
      timeStamp: 0,
      newItem: "Test"
    };

    componentDidMount() {
      const min = 1;
      const max = 100;
      const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      this.setState({ timeStamp: this.state.timeStamp + rand });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <WrappedComponent {...this.state} {...this.props} />
      )
    }
  }
  return RequestAnimationFrame;
};

const App = ({ timeStamp, newItem }) => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <h1>{timeStamp}</h1>
    <p>{newItem}</p>
  </div>
);

const arrayItems = ["EnhancedApp", "EnhancedApp2"];
const Products = ({ items }) => {
  return (
    items.map((item, index)  => (
      item = withRequestAnimationFrame()(App)
    ))
  )
};

function Product() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Products items={arrayItems} />
    </div>
  )
}

render(<Product />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This line is the problem:

   ```
   item = withRequestAnimationFrame()(App)
   ```

   What your doing there is assigning result of withRequestAnimationFrame()(App) 
   function to item which is definetly not what you wanted. I assume you wanted to 
   render there multiple instances of withRequestAnimationFrame component. You can 
   do it like this:

   ```
   items.map((item, index)  => (
       const NewComponent = withRequestAnimationFrame(item)(App);
       return <NewComponent key={index}/>
   ))
   ```
2. Second problem is that you are not passing item prop to the wrapped component. 
   To pass item prop you should do:

   ```
   const withRequestAnimationFrame = (item) => WrappedComponent => {
      class RequestAnimationFrame extends React.Component {
          state = {
              timeStamp: 0,
              newItem: item
          };
   ```

Comment: No Dice! "const arrayItems = ["EnhancedApp", "EnhancedApp2"];
const Products = ({ items }) => {
  return items.map(item => {
      return withRequestAnimationFrame(item)(App)
    })
};"

Comment: Yea, I just wanted a new instance. "newItem" was just a placeholder but good looking out. :)